# Flexbox masonry with expandable content

Tags: flexbox, masonry

I'm looking for a way to replace masonry grid with flexbox. The challenge I'm facing is that the content I have is expandable. Is there a known solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I thought this might help: https://jsfiddle.net/kunji/t91xppcx/

This is basically a responsive flexbox grid and on the third item in the grid I have added some content that can be shown when you click more. Items in the row below move down while the content in the box above expands.

This is what I used on the More content (JQuery):

```
    var $clickme = $('.clickme'),
        $box = $('.box');

    $box.hide();

    $clickme.click( function(e) {
        $(this).text(($(this).text() === 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide')).next('.box').slideToggle();;
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: yes, that's fine, but it's the example above isn't exactly a masonry grid, ie. it expands all boxes, not just the one with content appended to it.

Comment: You can change   
-webkit-align-items: flex-start;
align-items: flex-start; 
in the css and this will give items their individual heights.